# File.Replace doesn't work on shared driver?

Tags: c#

The following code works when the files are local.

```
var tmp = @"c:\dir\tmp.txt";
var target = @"c:\dir\target.txt";
var backup = @"c:\dir\backup10.txt";
File.Replace(tmp, target, backup);
```

However, it gets the Exception of "Access to the path is denied" if the files are on a shared drive.

```
// m:\Shared is mapped to a shared folder. And it has permissions on the folder.
var tmp = @"m:\Shared\tmp.txt";
var target = @"m:\Shared\target.txt";
var backup = @"m:\Shared\backup10.txt";
File.Replace(tmp, target, backup); // Error!
```

The [File.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.replace?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_File_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_) document doesn't mention shared directory?

Comment: Hmm, how come you deleted the previous question about this? Anyhow, I wonder if it's because it's a mapped network drive, and because `File.Replace` maintains security attributes and such, maybe that's not allowed on the network drive?

Comment: What happens if you pass `ignoreMetadataErrors: true` to the `Replace()` method?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, no exception after passing the parameter

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you able to perform the same action with Windows Explorer on the network path **m:\Shared**?

Comment: @MattU/@MickyD, the issue is resolved by peter's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether this will work on a network share will depend on the share. But, it's instructive to look at the underlying native Win32 API that .NET is calling, the [`ReplaceFile()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-replacefilew).

Of particular note are the access rights required for proper handling of each file specified in the call. For example:

> `lpReplacementFileName`
>
> The name of the file that will replace the *lpReplacedFileName* file.
>
> …
>
> The function attempts to open this file with the **SYNCHRONIZE**, **GENERIC_READ**, **GENERIC_WRITE**, **DELETE**, and **WRITE_DAC** access rights so that it can preserve all attributes and ACLs. If this fails, the function attempts to open the file with the **SYNCHRONIZE**, **GENERIC_READ**, **DELETE**, and **WRITE_DAC** access rights. No sharing mode is specified.

Any of these rights could be problematic, depending on the share. But in your case, I believe you're running into the **`WRITE_DAC`** access right.

As you've confirmed in your comment above, when you pass `ignoreMetadataErrors: true` the call succeeds. This means that when the underlying `ReplaceFile()` function is called, the **`REPLACEFILE_IGNORE_MERGE_ERRORS`** flag is passed (see the actual call on Microsoft's source code site: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,d4b8da02b41f19a4), causing errors involving **`WRITE_DAC`** to be ignored.

Since we don't have access to your share, it's impossible to know for sure. But I'd put dollars to donuts that in your case, you don't have the `WRITE_DAC` access right on the share, and so the call fails.

As long as you don't mind the ACL and other file attributes not being copied, the answer is to pass `ignoreMetadataErrors: true` to the method.

If you do mind those things not being copied, then you should simply be thankful for the exception, which alerts you to the fact that what you're trying to do is unsupported, and that you need to correct the configuration of your share so that it works as you'd like (note that if the share is hosted on a file system that doesn't support Windows-style ACLs, it might be impossible to get it to work).

Comment: What will `File.Replace()` do if anther application is reading the target file? Will it wait for the reading? or change the files while reading?

Comment: _"What will File.Replace() do if anther application is reading the target file?"_ -- that will depend on what file share options are used by the other application. You can read the `ReplaceFile()` documentation to see what access and share options it uses. As long as those don't conflict with the other application, the call will succeed. But if they do -- e.g. the other application does not use `FILE_SHARE_READ` on the target file -- then the call would fail.

Comment: Note that to some extent, you may not want to concern yourself with these specific types of conflicts. When dealing with I/O of any sort, including file I/O, exceptions are a fact of life. Your code needs to be able to react to the exceptions gracefully, catching and handling them as they occur. It will often be up to the user to fix whatever the actual problem is.

Comment: The one case I want to avoid. For example, when using two renamings, target => backup, and then tmp -> target. There is a slight chance that other applications cannot find the target file during the two renamings. Will `File.Replace` prevents it happening?

Comment: _"Will File.Replace prevents it happening?"_ -- I don't know. That seems like an entirely new question to me. Note thought, the whole point of `File.Replace()` is to provide an atomic operation. You've got a race, which means that it's indeterminate _which_ version of the file another application might open. But I think it very likely that it will always open _some_ version of the file. Otherwise, the whole `ReplaceFile()` function seems broken to me.

Comment: Yes, it should meet our requirements as long as it's atomic.